# Databricks; Table ACL; Unable to change table ownership

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to set up RBAC for tables in my Azure Databricks workspace by following 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/access-control/table-acl

I'm able to create tables, however the owner is being set to 'root' and not the user name which I'm using. 
 `ALTER TABLE <table-name> OWNER TO <workspace-user>` doesn't have any on table ownership. What could be wrong?

Comment: I am getting this error when I am using Overwrite option.